# Format content of Jquery-UI programatically created Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

My application creates an accordion (within another) programatically from data drawn from a database. My question is how can I format said data, adding paragraphs etc. HTML within the text: field is printed literally even when added as a variable.

```
$('#accordion2').append($('<h3>', {
    id: name,
    text: clientAddress,
    activate: function () {
        gev.trigger(marker, 'click');
    },
    mouseover: function () {
        gev.trigger(marker, 'click');
    },
    mouseout: function () {
        gev.trigger(marker, 'mouseout');
    },
}));

$('#accordion2').append($('<div>', {
    text: "Client Name: " + clientName + " Job Number: " + jobNo + " Property Type: " + propType
})).accordion('destroy').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help and if you have any questions on the code just ask.

Swires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using append incorrectly. Try this.

```
$('#accordion2').append("<div> Client Name: " + clientName + "<br/> Job Number: " + jobNo + " <br/>Property Type: " + propType + " </div>"}))
```

Code is adding `br` tags between each item in your list but obviously you could add any markup.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the quick and concise answer. Fairly new to JQuery (and front-end work in general), nice to have support.

Comment: No problem. Get familiar with the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/) it's usually very very good. My other tip would be to get to grips with the chrome inspector and console. Once you get the hang of debugging javascript most issues are much easier to solve.